# How to Have multiple If statements in PHP

Tags: magento-1.7, php, magento-1, template

I want to add this:

```
<?php if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?>
```

To This Statement:

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'checkout'):?>
<?php else:?>
<div>test</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a PHP question not related to Magento.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if any of us understand your question. May be the following link will help you

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

So it goes by saying

```
<?php if (condition) : ?>
  HTML contents
<?php elseif (condition) : ?>
  HTML contents
<?php else : ?>
  HTML contents
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that is what your are looking for. BTW this has nothing to do with Magento.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an AND condition:

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'checkout' && Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?>
<?php else:?>
<div>test</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

If you want an OR condition:

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'checkout' || Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()):?>
<?php else:?>
<div>test</div>
<?php endif;?>
```